# How to set limit in input type number in html form

Tags: html, forms

Hey everyone can anyone tell me where I am wrong in the following HTML attribute-
I just want to make the limit=10, keytype only numbers, no ondrop/onpaste

```
<input required type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' name="phone" placeholder=" " maxlenght="10">
```

Comment: `maxlength`. not `maxlenght`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo. Should be `maxlength`

```
<input required type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' name="phone" placeholder=" "maxlength= "10">
```